# nvl() function in php file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just looking through a php file and have come across the following code:

```
switch (nvl($mode))
{
  case "add" :
     print_add_category_form(nvl($id, 0));
     break;

  case "edit" :
     print_edit_category_form($id);
     break;
}
```

What does the nvl() function do??

Comment: Have you tried a "find in files" search?  Look for "function nvl" to figure out where it is; like CJ said, nvl isn't a standard function.

Answer (score 7):

Probably it would be like Oracle's NVL function, although as far as I know that expects two parameters.

I searched Google Code Search with PHP as the language and there are several examples such as this:

```
/**
* If $var is undefined, return $default, otherwise return $var.
*/
function nvl(&$var, $default = "")
{
    return isset($var) ? $var
                       : $default;
}
```

I think however you would be better off looking for the declaration in the code yourself as ceejayoz suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Or if you have access to PHP 7.0.0, try the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) "??"

So instead of (Oracle syntax):

```
nvl($id, 0)
```

You can use:

```
$id ?? 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Who knows? It's not a standard PHP function. Look elsewhere in the code for where that function is defined.

Comment: oh ok. I have looked through and couldn't find a nvl function, so assumed it must be a standard one. Thanks anyways!

Comment: In the future, going to http://php.net/nvl will let you know if it's a standard function or not.

Answer (score 1):

See the link below for the definition of nvl() as used by Oracle. PHP has none. So, the developer of your code example might have implemented a similar function.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

In my codes I use my own implementation, which is closer to what Oracle defined:

**By the way: "nvl" just means "[n]ull [v]a[l]ue"**

```
// Function: nvl
//
// Replaces null or '' string.
//
// PARAMETERS:
//   $val     - Value to be returned normally.
//   $replace - Value to be returned if $val is null or ''.
//
// RETURNS:
//   See parameters.

function nvl($val, $replace)
{
    if( is_null($val) || $val === '' )  return $replace;
    else                                return $val;
}
```