# What is the php function to simultaneously check the existence of a $_GET parameter and access its value

Tags: php, superglobals

In PHP, to avoid `Undefined Index` errors, one can write

```
if(isset $_GET['var1'] && $_GET['var1'] == 'My Matching Text'){
    //do stuff
}
```

But I remember using a function (or language construct) that I think would allow something like this:

```
if([THE FUNCTION I'M LOOKING FOR]($_GET['var1']) == 'My Matching Text'){
    //do stuff
}
```

What is this function whose name I have forgotten?

Comment: I tried Google and php.net, but I failed at both searches.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `nvl` equivalent. I don't believe there's such a function but it's easy to make your own or use a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569790/10400050), or another [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569790/10400050)

Comment: "Undefined Index" is a mere warning, not a blocking error. I almost feel dirty to suggest it, but this seems like a perfect use case for the `@` warning suppressor.

Comment: isset($_GET['var1']) does the work

Comment: I accepted the answer from Don'tPanic because it answers my question as written. I upvoted the answer from NigelRen because I learned a valuable new tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of the [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function?

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'var1') == 'My Matching Text') {
    //do stuff
}
```

It takes a third argument where you can specify different filter types, which can be useful. The default type doesn't filter at all, but it will return the value (or null if the key isn't set) without an undefined index notice.

I don't know how this compares in terms of performance to using the null coalescing operator like the other answers show, but I would assume this function call would be a little more expensive, so the operator would be a better way to go unless you are going to use one of the filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Null coalescing operator (??)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) in PHP 7+ which allows you to set a 'not defined' value (I've used blank `''` in this example)...

```
if(($_GET['var1']??'') == 'My Matching Text'){
    //do stuff
}
```